# Crawl Web Data using Web Crawler

Tags: java, web-crawler

I would like to use a web crawler and crawl a particular website. The website is a learning management system where many student upload their assignments,project presentations and so on. My question is that can i use a web crawler and download the files that have been uploaded in the learning management system. After i download them i would like to create an index on them so as to query the set of documents. User can use my application as a search engine. Can a crawler does this? I know about webeater ( Crawler written in Java )

Comment: if you can manually view the assignments, presentations and such, than a crawler can too.

Comment: i can view them as a link which when clicked gets downloaded..

Comment: "I would like to use a web crawler and crawl a particular website."  What website?  What is the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the files in Java SingleThread.
2. Parse the files (you can get idea from parse plugins of nutch).
3. Create index with lucene

Comment: i didnot understand step1. what is SingleThread in Java. I know threads in java. Can u provide more info about this??

Comment: Recommending Lucene for a task as small-scale as this is the most ridiculous thing I've ever heard.. use SQLite, you'll be finished in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a real webcrawler, user http://www.httrack.com/

It offers you so many options for copying websites or content on webpages including flash.  It works on windows and mac.

Then you can do steps 2 and 3 as suggested above.